# Match whole Ruby-style string with _replacements_ in Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match single Ruby-style string with *replacements*, that looks like:

`"some ugly text #{Class.new().method("argument")}"`

As you may see the nasty thing is that it allows double-quotes to be present inside the template without escape.

I need to catch whole text between corner double-quotes as a single string. Do not need further processing of `replacements`.

I would like to do it in a single regular expression to feed my simple tokenizer.

Comment: Whoever answers this: be aware that ruby allows curly braces in the escaped part: `"funny thing: #{{hash: 'within "string"'}}"`

Comment: How are you doing your tokenizer... surely the grammar would be inside a quotedstring, a #{ until an unescaped } is a replacement, which means you should "tokenize" on #{ and } possibly... Otherwise, you're not really tokenizing, you're trying to parse using a regex, and that'd not be a good idea

Comment: I am not writing new Ruby - I need the content of the text between double quotes, without any processing. Just the content. It seems I found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following seem to work:

```
>>> check = re.compile(r'("((#\{([^}]|["])*\})|\\.|[^"])*")|(\'(\\.|[^\'])*\')').match
>>> check('"Text"').end()
6
>>> check('"Text #{}"').end()
10
>>> check('"Text #{"}"').end()
11
>>> check('"Text #{""}"').end()
12
>>> check('"Text #{"foo"}"').end()
16
```

Sometimes just asking the question helps with solving the problem. My tokenizer starts working correctly with that regular expression, so problem solved.

The tricky part is `([^}]|["])*` which consumes what is inside the `replacement`, surrounded by `#{}`, gives `#\{([^}]|["])*\}`. I currently don't need double curly braces.

Last part consumes strings in single quotes, so don't be surprised.